# log4net windowsService remotingAppender won't log when built in release mode

Tags: c#, log4net

I have two windowsServices.

WindowsService B is configured as the RemotingAppender server, while WindowsService A is the client.

If I build both projects in debug mode and install them as a service in Windows 10, WindowsService A can communicate with WindowsService B and WindowsService B logs to a file.

If I build WindowsService B (the RemotingAppender server) in release mode (with Optimize Code checked), it no longer logs to the file. If I rebuild in Release config again, but with Optimize Code **unchecked**, it will begin to log again. Take note that the services, in all scenarios, are being installed as a service in Windows.

Comment: have you checked that article in docs? https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#log-early

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. You have resolved my issue. I had to remove the Assembly decalaration and use ConfigureAndWatch in the constructor instead.